# Unpublish an article on a specific date in django

Tags: django

I have a simple article model with pub_date field and a unpublish_date field.

Is there any way to automagically set my is_published field to False when the unpublish_date is in the past?

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    post = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True,)

    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    unpublish_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=True,)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply factor this `unpublish_date` into your queries, for example:

```
articles_to_show = Articles.objects.filter(is_published=True,
                                        unpublish_date__gt=datetime.date.today())
```

This is likely to make your code more complicated, though. You'd have to rewrite all your queries to be aware of the `unpublish_date`.

Cron works for this sort of thing but is only good for changing things in large batches once or a few times a day. It doesn't scale well when you have a large batch of tasks to do or want more fine-grained scheduling.

If running a task via cron once per day is sufficient, do that. It might be worth investigating more advanced options such as message queues, though.

To make a scheduled task which will run at a precise time (provided a worker is available), I would use [Celery](http://celeryproject.org/).

```
from celery.decorators import task

@task
def unpublish(article_pk):
    article = Article.objects.get(pk=article_pk)
    article.is_published = False
    article.save()

# Unpublish article in exactly 7 days from now
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
unpublish.apply_async([article.pk], eta=datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(7))
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible without a bit of custom code… But that custom code is pretty simple:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.unpublished_date < datetime.now():
        self.is_published = True
    super(Article, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

(of course, make sure you're doing the correct timezone conversion on `self.unpublished_date`, if that applies…)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to create some scheduled job that will run on some time interval, check for articles ready to be unpublished and unpublish them.

For such cases I do following things:

1. [create custom manage.py command](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/) that will do your logic. In this case it will be looking for the articles that can be unpublished and change their flag to `unpublished`
2. set up `cron` to launch this command every X minutes/hours

You can also use [djnago-chronograph](http://code.google.com/p/django-chronograph/) - this app helps to manage over scheduled tasks in your application.

Answer (score 0):

Using the snippet: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/838/ solved most of my problem! But now I have come across a new problem.

Im using the fantastic [django-template-utils](http://code.google.com/p/django-template-utils/) to display the app on every web-page.

If I do this:

```
objects = ActiveManager(from_date='pub_date', to_date='unpublish_date')
```

I get only the active objects, but in then they disapear from admin also. Do anyone know if there is some way to get django-templates-utils to use a custom modelManager, instead of the standard one? Or is there a way to use a modelmanager that hides un-active post on the front-end, but will display them in admin?